# [1]+ Exit 125 nohup

Tags: bash, shell, command, nohup

I am running the following command:

```
nohup ./run_hyper_param_tuning.sh> ../../logs/hyper_model_15_b_Jan.txt 2>&1  & echo $! >save_pid.txt
```

It has been always working but suddenly it stopped working now. The script is the following:

```
#!/bin/bash

export PATH=/usr/local/cuda-9.0/bin${PATH:+:${PATH}}
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/cuda/lib64:${LD_LIBRARY_PATH:+:${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}}

#added by Anaconda3 installer
export PATH="/home/javier/anaconda3/envs/AIenv/bin:$PATH"
#export PATH="/home/javier/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"

#source /home/javier/anaconda3/bin/activate AIenv

echo "STARTING HYPER-PARAMETER TUNING..."
backbones=("resnet101")
gradient_clip_norms=(10)
learning_rates=(0.001)
weight_decays=(0.0005)
layers=('heads')

for i in "${backbones[@]}"
do
  for j in "${gradient_clip_norms[@]}"
  do
    for k in "${learning_rates[@]}"
    do
      for l in "${weight_decays[@]}"
      do
        for m in "${layers[@]}"
        do
         echo "-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------"
         echo  "backbone:" $i " gradient_clip_norms:" $j " learning_rate:" $k " weight_decays:" $l "layers:" $m
         echo "-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------"
            python3 custom.py train --dataset=customImages/ --weights=coco --backbone=$i --grad_clip_norms=$j --learn_rate=$k --weight_decays=$l --layers=$m --epochs=100
         echo "successfully done"
        done
      done
    done
  done
done
```

The file where I redirect the output has the following message:

```
[1]+  Exit 125                nohup ./run_hyper_param_tuning.sh > ../../logs/hyper_model_15_b_Jan.txt 2>&1
```

However when I show again the content with cat, the file is empty.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 2):

This, according to the (GNU) `nohup` documentation, is `nohup` itself failing.

```
-bash-4.2$ man nohup | grep 125
-bash-4.2$ info nohup | grep 125
info: Writing node (coreutils.info.gz)nohup invocation...
info: Done.
     125 if 'nohup' itself fails, and 'POSIXLY_CORRECT' is not set
instead of 125.
```

Perhaps try a `strace` of `nohup` to see what it is failing over?

Comment: I have solved it. I did not have enough space storage, I removed multiple folders and the command works again well.